# Swift Compiler Error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'String'

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am using Swift playgrounds and learning about parameters in Lesson 9 of *Intro to Swift*.

```swift
func sing(verb: String, noun: String) {
    print("\(verb), \(verb), \(verb) your \(noun)")
}

let line = sing(verb: "Row", noun: "Boat")
```

The last line gives me this warning:

> Constant 'line' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected.

When I explicitly define the constant as a String—`let line: String = sing(verb: "Row", noun: "Boat")`—I get the following error:

> error: cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'String'

I'm not sure what to do in order to resolve this.

Side note: If you have suggestions for how to make the function read more like a sentence, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Please, consider the Swift function tutorial.

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov I already read and reviewed it. I wouldn't have asked the question if I could have found the answer myself haha, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `sing()` is not returning a `String` object.

Hence you cannot use `variable = void function()` as it’s not a valid assignment operation.

You can specify `String` as a return type of `sing()`, and return the string you are printing in the function. That will solve your problem.

```
func sing(verb: String, noun: String) -> String {   
  return "\(verb), \(verb), \(verb) your \(noun)"     
}

let line = sing(verb: "Row", noun: "Boat")
```

Comment: How do I make the function return a String?

Comment: Awesome, that makes much more sense. Thank you!